# Running a class in a separate thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, qt, pyside

I can't launch the browser in a separate thread.

I have this code:

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

class browser(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_until_complete(self.main())


    async def main(self):
        url = 'https://example.com'
        browser = await launch(headless=True)
        page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.goto(url, waitUntil='networkidle0')
```

When calling, this error comes out:

```
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter
```

If you run it without QThread then everything works

Comment: So why don't you run it without `QThread` then?

Comment: Python only raises system system signals on the main thread. Code that depends on signals may be restricted - hence the error message. It seems like this is an async module so you would naturally run it on the main thread with the rest of your async code. That's the point of async - get rid of synchronization dependencies among threads. If this code really does need to run independently, a child process may be the better option.

Comment: @V.K. Since this is a GUI program on QT. If you insert it into the main thread without QThread, then everything works, then the program interface freezes